# Xamarin forms Change and enable image button

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

[Sample UI design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sxari.png)

Does anyone know how to change Imagebutton source? Refer to the picture link, when user click on step1 (MainPage), it will redirect user to another page (SecondPage). Once user click on "done" button in SecondPage, I want to change my imagebutton source and at the same time, enable click event. I am not sure not to call the function from one page to another.

(P.S my btnclickcount doesn't seems to be working sometimes... I only want to record the start date time on first button click)

```
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
    public string mainpagevalue;

    int offlinecount = 0;
    int onlinecount = 0;

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }
    private void btnOffline_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        offlinecount++;
        txtOfflineStatus.Text = "IN PROGRESS";

        Navigation.PushAsync(new SecondPage(this, lblEndDT, txtOfflineStatus, btnOnline, btnMH));


        if (offlinecount == 1)
        {
            string currentDT = DateTime.Now.ToString();
            lblStartDT.Text = currentDT;
        }


    }

    private void btnOnline_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        onlinecount++;

        txtOnlineStatus.Text = "IN PROGRESS";

        Navigation.PushAsync(new ThirdPage(this, lblOnlineEndDT, btnTS, txtOnlineStatus));

        if (onlinecount == 1)
        {
            string onlinestartDT = DateTime.Now.ToString();
            lblOnlineStartDT.Text = onlinestartDT;
        }

    }
```

Third Page

```
 public partial class ThirdPage : ContentPage
{
    Label wopLblOnlineEndDT;
    MainPage mainpage;
    ImageButton btntroubleshoot;
    Label wolblOnlineStatus;

    public ThirdPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }
    public ThirdPage(MainPage woPage, Label lblOnlineEndDT, ImageButton btnTS, Label lblOnlineStatus)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        mainpage = woPage;
        wopLblOnlineEndDT = lblOnlineEndDT;
        btntroubleshoot = btnTS;
        wolblOnlineStatus = lblOnlineStatus;
    }
    private void BtnDone_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string edt = DateTime.Now.ToString();
        wopLblOnlineEndDT.Text = edt;
        mainpage.mainpagevalue = wopLblOnlineEndDT.Text;
        btntroubleshoot.Source = "troubleshooting";
        btntroubleshoot.IsEnabled = true;
        wolblOnlineStatus.Text = "COMPLETED";
        wolblOnlineStatus.TextColor = Color.FromRgb(0, 214, 54);
        Navigation.PopAsync();
    }
}
```

XAML

```
 <ImageButton x:Name="btnOffline" IsEnabled="True" Source="@drawable/offlinetool.png" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" BackgroundColor="Transparent" Clicked="btnOffline_Clicked"/>
        <Label Text="Offline Tool" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Margin="15,0,0,0"/>
        <ImageButton Source="@drawable/material.png" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" BackgroundColor="Transparent"/>
        <Label Text="Material Handler" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1" />
        <Image Source="@drawable/Picture1.png" Grid.Row="6" Grid.ColumnSpan="6" BackgroundColor="Transparent"/>

        <Label Text="Start Date Time:" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3"/>
        <Label Text="End Date Time:" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3" Margin="7,40,0,0"/>
        <Label Text="Status:" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="3" Margin="58,0,0,0" />
        <Label x:Name="txtOfflineStatus" Text="NOT STARTED" TextColor="Red" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="2"/>
        <Label x:Name="lblStartDT" Text="" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="1"/>
        <Label x:Name="lblEndDT" Text="-" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,40,0,0"/>

        <Label Text="Start Date Time:" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="3"  />
        <Label Text="End Date Time:" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="3" Margin="7,40,0,0"/>
        <Label Text="Status:" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="3" Margin="58,0,0,0" />
        <Label Text="NOT STARTED" TextColor="Red" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="5"/>


        <!--#Online Tool-->
        <ImageButton x:Name="btnOnline" Source="@drawable/ot.png" Grid.Row="8" Grid.Column="1" BackgroundColor="Transparent" Clicked="btnOnline_Clicked" IsEnabled="False"/>
        <Label Text="Online Tool" Grid.Row="9" Grid.Column="1" Margin="19,0,0,0"/>
        <ImageButton x:Name="btnMH" Source="@drawable/mh.png" Grid.Row="11" Grid.Column="1" BackgroundColor="Transparent" Clicked="imgbtnMH_Clicked" IsEnabled="False"/>
        <Label Text="Material Handler" Grid.Row="12" Grid.Column="1"/>
        <Image Source="@drawable/Picture1.png" Grid.Row="13" Grid.ColumnSpan="6" BackgroundColor="Transparent"/>

        <Label Text="Start Date Time:" Grid.Row="8" Grid.Column="3" />
        <Label Text="End Date Time:" Grid.Row="8" Grid.Column="3" Margin="7,40,0,0"/>
        <Label Text="Status:" Grid.Row="9" Grid.Column="3" Margin="58,0,0,0" />
        <Label Text="NOT STARTED" TextColor="Red" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="9"/>
        <Label x:Name="lblOnlineStartDT" Text="00:00:00" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="8"/>
        <Label x:Name="lblOnlineEndDT" Text="" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="8" Margin="0,40,0,0"/>
        <Label x:Name="txtOnlineStatus" Text="NOT STARTED" TextColor="Red" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="9"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the reference of `imageButton` to the `SecondPage` too and change the `Source` in the done method. Let me show you how to do it:

In the **MainPage** xaml, create an `ImageButton` named `MyImageButton`:

```
<StackLayout>
    <!-- Place new controls here -->

    <Label x:Name="lblStartDT" Text="startTest" 
           HorizontalOptions="Center"
           VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>

    <Button Text="go to secondPage" Clicked="btnOffline_Clicked"  HorizontalOptions="Center"
       VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>

    <Label x:Name="lblEndDT" Text="endTest" 
       HorizontalOptions="Center"
       VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />

    <ImageButton x:Name="MyImageButton" Source="Images.png" IsEnabled="False" 
                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />

</StackLayout>
```

In code behind, pass `MyImageButton` to the SecondPage:

```
    private void btnOffline_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Pass the parametere you need when you go to SecondPage 
        //Navigation.PushAsync(new SecondPage(this, lblEndDT));

        Navigation.PushAsync(new SecondPage(this, lblEndDT, MyImageButton));

        string currentDT = DateTime.Now.ToString();
        lblStartDT.Text = currentDT;

    }
```

In the SecondPage, get the reference of `myImageBtn` and modify it in the `done` method:

```
public partial class SecondPage : ContentPage
{
    Label MainPagelblEndDT;
    MainPage mainPage;
    ImageButton myImageBtn;
    public SecondPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public SecondPage(MainPage mainP,Label lblEndDT)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //Get the lblEndDT reference here
        MainPagelblEndDT = lblEndDT;
        //Get the MainPage reference here
        mainPage = mainP;
    }

    public SecondPage(MainPage mainP, Label lblEndDT, ImageButton imageBtn)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //Get the lblEndDT reference here
        MainPagelblEndDT = lblEndDT;
        //Get the MainPage reference here
        mainPage = mainP;
        //Get the ImageButton reference here
        myImageBtn = imageBtn;
    }

    private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {           
        string edt = DateTime.Now.ToString();

        //Use it
        MainPagelblEndDT.Text = edt;      

        mainPage.previouspagevalue = MainPagelblEndDT.Text;

        //change the source of imageBtn
        myImageBtn.Source = "Images1";
        myImageBtn.IsEnabled = true;

        Navigation.PopAsync();
    }
}
```

A sample project is available [here](https://github.com/XfHua/pass-value).

Comment: Hi, thank you for the help again! Really appreciate it. Can I clarify about creating public secondpage? When you do a navigation.pushasync on main page, does it only apply to that particular button click event and their variables declared in xaml? Because I tried changing another image button source on my btnoffline click event, it doesn't work. I thought passing in the variables in public secondpage means that it is calling the button ID?

Comment: @Charis All you need to do is get the reference of the control you want to change. Show us the code which doesn't work and then we can help you better.

Comment: Hi I've updated my code. I want to change the myimagebutton2 source and keep the myimagebutton source. But after I click the button, it overlapped.

Comment: I got it worked after adjusting a few codes! :) Thank you! I still have problems with my time stamp. I am not sure is it because of the pushasync, my button click count will restart so my condition does not work

Comment: Where is the code about the  click count? BTW, can you please mark this answer if it solves your problem.

Comment: @Charis Move this line out of the method:  `int btnclickcount = 0;`.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for the first button only. I can't reuse btnclickcount for other functions right? Because when every button is enabled each time, I also want to do a click count and get the first click.

Comment: Yes, you can't reuse it as it is increasing every time you click the button.

Comment: Okay thank you! Do you have any idea will my label gets overlapped? It works well for the first page navigation, subsequently, it gets overlapped. Is this happening because of the popasync? Since I keep going back to previous page, so my label gets overlapped as well

Comment: No, keep going back to previous page won't overlap the label. I need to see codes to find out the problem.

Comment: Hi, I updated my code already. I did exactly the same as my second page but only third page will overlap

Comment: You are putting lblOnlineStartDT and lblOnlineEndDT in the same Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="8".

Comment: The date time is fine, I set margin so they are not overlapped. But for the status, it overlaps. I tried coding on another new project, it doesn't overlap even if after navigation, so I am not sure why my current code does not work the same way when I code the same thing :(

Comment: Maybe overlapped by the margin?

Answer (score 0):

Bind the button Opacity to something like 0.5 and also disable the button.

```
                    <ImageButton Command="{Binding EditActivityCommand}"
                                 BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                                 Opacity="{Binding Opacity}"
                                 IsEnabled="{Binding IsAdmin}">
```